# Function that can take as an argument either id or array with that id

Tags: php

I have a function that takes `user id` as an argument, and returns array of `user data`:

```
function user_get_data( $user_id ) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'";
    ...
    return $user_data; // associative array
}
```

Usage:

```
$user_data = user_get_data( 123 );
var_dump( $user_data );

// Outputs:
// array (size=2)
//  'id' => int 123
//  'name' => string 'Juan Vitelli' (length=12)
```

And I have a function that takes `user id`, and returns count of posts of that user:

```
function user_get_post_count( $user_id ) {
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
    ...
    return $post_count;
}
```

Now I want to rewrite `user_get_post_count()` function so it can take as an argument either `user id` directly, or `user data` array returned by `user_get_data()` function, which contains that id. Something like this...

```
function user_get_post_count( $user_data_or_id ) {
    // get user id
    if( is_array( $user_data_or_id ) ) {
        $user_id = $user_data_or_id[ "id" ];
    } else {
        $user_id = $user_data_or_id;
    }

    // get post count
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
    ...
    return $post_count;
}
```

I just want to know if something like this is considered as good practice or if there is better way. If it is good practice my next question is if `$user_data_or_id` is suitable variable name for what I am doing.

Comment: Why do you want to have both? Is it a requirement?

Comment: i would simply put the variable name as `$user`

Comment: @amrhady In reality I have functions like this that does more work than just fetch number from db by user id.
For example imagine that I want to have a function that outputs html link to specific user, like this `return "<a href='user.php?id={$user_data[ "id" ]}'>{$user_data[ "name" ]}</a>"`. Sometimes I have just `user_id` availibile and I need to get user_data first. But when I have whole user_data array availibile before calling the function I can just pass it to that function and that's all, so I don't need another db query.

Comment: Are you using functional programming? Or do you have  a "user" class?

Comment: @amrhady It's procedural, so just functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches to this. You may want to read a bit about ORM, Active Record, Data Mapper, Query Object.

In your context, I don't see a point of passing an array just to extract the "user_id" from it. If you are passing an array, i would say that this is indicating that you're looking for "posts" by more than one "user_id", or according to a specific criteria. That is, in another more general context, you are building your query based on the input parameter. And in that case, it would indeed be better to pass a filter array.

For example, your array might look like this:

```
array('user_id' => 7, 'title'=>'abc','ts_created'=>1234567, 'published'=>1, ...)
```

And using some SQL syntax builder, you would end up with a query like this:

```
SELECT 
        *
FROM 
        `posts`
WHERE 
        `user_id` = 7 AND
        `title` LIKE '%abc%' AND
        `ts_created` >= 1234567 AND
        `published` = 1
        .
        .
        .
```

As you can see, this would return a resultset that matches your search criteria. If you criteria specifies a "userID", then you would get back "posts" only by this user in the results.

To do this in OOP, there's also several approaches. If you want to map the above to a simple "User" class, you could do:

```
class User{

    public function getByID($userID){

        //sql query
        $query = "SELECT FROM users where user_id = $userID"

        //execute query and return results
    }
}
```

But as you can see, this is not very flexible if you want to specify more filter criteria for the SQL query. To make it more flexible, taking "Posts" as an example, you can create a "Post" class:

```
class Post{
    /*
    * This is not a working code, just an example to give you an idea.
    */

    protected $mSQLBuilder;
    protected $mTable = 'posts';

    public function __construct(){
        $this->mSQLBuilder = new SQLBuilder($this->mTable);
    }

    public function search($filter = array()){

        //
        $criteria = array('fields'=>array('*'),'filters'=>$filter); 

        //
        $query = $sqlBuilder->build($criteria);

        //
        return $query->execute()->fetchAll();

    }

    public function count($filter){

        //
        $criteria = array('fields'=>array('count(*)'),'filters'=>$filter);

        //
        $query = $sqlBuilder->build($criteria);

        //
        return $query->execute()->fetch();

    }

    public function setSQLBuilder($builder){
        $this->sqlBuilder = $builder;
    }
}
```

Make sure you do a bit of reading about ORM and design patterns.